A polynomial and a root of maximum modulus
Let $r$ be the root (real or complex) of polynomial $P(x)=x^4+3x^3-3x^2+3x-1$ such that $r$ has  maximum modulus. Find the closest integer to $|r^7|$.
Using Bolzano's Theorem I know that the polynomial $P$ has a root approximately $-4$ and another approximately $-0.4$. But I dont know how to proceed to estimate to complex roots. Does anyone has any ideas? Thanks a lot!

note the 4 roots product is $-1$, and the other two complex roots are conjugate.

FWIW, the numerical solution is $x \approx -3.963836081004363$ and $x \approx 0.4266567317092336$ for the real roots, and $x \approx 0.2685896746475647 \pm 0.7205252495365454i$ (with a modulus of 0.7689584179570348) for the complex roots.  Thus, the maximum modulus is $3.963836081004363$, and the 7th power of that rounded to the nearest integer is $15375$.  I'm having a hard time finding an algebraic solution, though.

The reason there is a trick available is that all but one of the roots have norm less that $1.$  This follows from the comment by Yimin, with the fact that the product of the real roots has absolute value larger than $1.$  Label $r$  your approx $r \approx -4,$  label the other real $s \approx 0.4,$  then complex conjugates $u,v.$   The product $rs \approx -1.7$  has absolute value larger than $1,$ indeed larger than $\frac{169}{100}.$   The product $uv$   (which is positive) is less than $\frac{100}{169},$  so each $|u|, |v| < \frac{10}{13}.$
The elementary symmetric polynomials are $\sigma_1 = -3,$ next $\sigma_2 = -3,$ $\sigma_3 = -3,$ $\sigma_4 = -1.$
With that in mind,  what you do  is find
$$  S_0 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4$$
$$ S_1 = r + s + u + v  = -3  $$
$$ S_2 = r^2 + s^2 + u^2 + v^2 = 15  $$
$$ S_3 = r^3 + s^3 + u^3 + v^3 = -63 $$
$$ S_4 = r^4 + s^4 + u^4 + v^4 ..... $$
$$ S_7 = r^7 + s^7 + u^7 + v^7 ..... $$
Then $$S_4 = - 3 S_3 + 3 S_2 - 3 S_1 + S_0 $$
$$S_5 = - 3 S_4 + 3 S_3 - 3 S_2 + S_1 $$
$$S_6 = - 3 S_5 + 3 S_4 - 3 S_3 + S_2 $$
$$S_7 = - 3 S_6 + 3 S_5 - 3 S_4 + S_3 $$
The point being that $|s^7|, |u^7|, |v^7| $ are fairly small compared with $1,$  so the nearest integer to $r^7$  is $S_7$   From the $10/13$ business, we get $|u^7| < \frac{1}{5}$
Afterthought, that business with $S_0 = 4$  seems a bit strange. We have roots $r,s,u,v$  Each has a relation analogous to $r^4 = -3 r^3 + 3 r^2 - 3 r +1.$    Grouping
$$  S_4 =   
-3 r^3 + 3 r^2 - 3 r +1
 -3 s^3 + 3 s^2 - 3 s +1
 -3 u^3 + 3 u^2 - 3 u +1
 -3 v^3 + 3 v^2 - 3 v +1 = $$
$$ -3 (r^3 + s^3 + u^3 + v^3) +3  (r^2 + s^2 + u^2 + v^2) -3 (r+s+u+v)  + 4 $$ $$ = -3 S_3 +3 S_2 -3 S_1 + S_0
$$
write out $S_5$
$$  S_5 =   
-3 r^4 + 3 r^3 - 3 r^2 + r
 -3 s^4 + 3 s^3 - 3 s^2 +s
 -3 u^4 + 3 u^3 - 3 u^2 +u
 -3 v^4 + 3 v^3 - 3 v^2 +v = $$
$$ -3 (r^4 + s^4 + u^4 + v^4) +3  (r^3 + s^3 + u^3 + v^3) -3 (r^2+s^2+u^2+v^2)  + (r+s+u+v) $$ $$ = -3 S_4 +3 S_3 -3 S_2 + S_1
$$
